# Mongo / Mongoid will create, but not update a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have an app which updates a post if it exists, otherwise it creates a new one. This post contains embedded documents:

```
class Post
  embeds_one :tag, :as => :taggable, :class_name => 'TagSnippet'
end

class TagSnippet
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name
  embedded_in :taggable, polymorphic: true
end
```

The post is updated in a controller with the following code:

```
@post = Post.where(--some criteria which work--).first
if @post
  @post.attributes = params
else
  @post = Post.new(params)
end

@post.save!
```

This code runs and updates the non-embedded documents, but does not update the embedded docs. Oddly, when I debug in Rubymine, all the attributes of the `@post` change appropriately (including the embedded ones), but regardless the database does not get updated.

This indicates to me it's some mongo or mongoid problem, but rolling back mongo and mongoid gems produced no change.

Answer (score 3):

I guess that your embedded document is defined like this:

```
field :subdoc, type: Hash
```

I bumped into this a couple of times already. Short explanation: Mongoid doesn't track changes inside subhashes.

```
doc.subdoc.field_a = 1 # won't be tracked

sd = doc.subdoc.dup
sd.field_a = 1
doc.subdoc = sd # should be tracked
```

So, if Mongoid doesn't detect assignments, it doesn't mark attribute dirty, and therefore doesn't include it in the update operation.

Check this theory by printing `doc.subdoc_changed?` before saving.

Comment: i actually used mongoid's embeds_one / embedded_in, and i've updated my answer to reflect that. thank you for the quick reply!

Comment: Anyway, check if my theory still holds.

Comment: `@post.tag_changed?` results in an error. `@post.tag.name_changed?` results in `true`, so it looks like it may be something else.

Comment: `@post.tag_changed?` results in `undefined method 'tag_changed?' for #<Post:0x007ffd48b37228>`

Comment: What's the output of `@post.methods.grep(/changed/)`?

Comment: it's an array of symbols of the format :created_at_changed, :type_changed, etc. There is no :tag_changed however

Comment: Hm, what about `@post.tag.changed?` then?

Comment: `@post.tag.changed` returns `true`, for both `@post.attributes = params` and `@post = Post.new(params)`